# Counting number of tosses to reach head

Tags: python

I am trying to get the number of tosses required to obtain the first head. I am runring the loop 10 times but the ouptut is getting stored only in the first cell of n. All the other cells of n are taking the default value of 1 stored in count. How to modify the loop so it stores values in all the 10 spaces of n.

```
import random
import numpy as np
Coin = [0,1]
array = np.zeros(10)
i = random.choice(Coin) # 0 for Heads
n = [0]*10
for j in range(10):
    count = 1
    while (i != 0):
        i = random.choice(Coin)
        count = count + 1
    n[j] = count
```

Comment: What have you done to try to resolve the issue? Have you done any debugging? As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1):

`while (i != 0):`, this line makes i = 0 after a number of repetition. Next time when the loop starts from `from j in range(10):`, it will find that `(i != 0)` equals to `False` and get out of the while loop. So, this simple correction will make your code fly:

```
import random
import numpy as np
Coin = [0,1]
array = np.zeros(10)
i = random.choice(Coin) # 0 for Heads
n = [0]*10
for j in range(10):
    count = 1
    while (i != 0):
        i = random.choice(Coin)
        count = count + 1
    i = random.choice(Coin)
    n[j] = count
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you didn't clear the value of `i`.

Take this:

```
import random
import numpy as np
Coin = [0,1]
n = [0]*10
for j in range(10):
    count = 1
    while True:
        i = random.choice(Coin)
        if i == 0:
            break
        count = count + 1
    n[j] = count
```

Then you can get what you want.

When `i` becomes 0 the first time, for the next for loop of `j`, `i != 0` never holds, so `count` is never updated later.

Answer (score 0):

I like what you have so far, but I feel like you have wayyy too many variables going on.

Try to simplify your code around the while loop:

```
import random

counter = 0
coinvalue = 1
while coinvalue == 1:
    coinvalue = random.randint(0, 1)
    counter += 1

print("Number of attempts to flip heads: " + str(counter))
```

This code does not store the coin flips into an array, however, if you are wishing to see how many flips it take to land a "heads" the array can be constructed afterwards using only the counter variable:

ex.
counter == 4
Array: Tails, Tails, Tails, Heads, ...

counter = 8
Array: Tails, Tails, Tails, Tails, Tails, Tails, Tails, ...

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend learning more Python, and about programming in general. Stack Overflow isn't the place to learn the very basics.

---

Here is a straightforward and clean solution, for the sake of it.

```py
import random


def count_tosses_to_head() -> int:
    curr_num_tosses = 1
    while (curr_outcome := random.randint(0, 1)) != 0:
        curr_num_tosses += 1
    return curr_num_tosses
```